# what is the syntax for Series.groupby(column) equivalent to DataFrame.groupby(column)?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to perform a groupby to a series, grouping by the values. e.g. count().
Suppose:

```
ser = pd.Series({'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb', 'c': 'ff', 'd': 'ff'})
ser.name= 'foo'
ser.index.name= 'idx'
```

so `ser` is:

```
idx
a    aa
b    bb
c    ff
d    ff
Name: foo, dtype: object
```

I could do:

```
>collections.Counter(ser)
Counter({'aa': 1, 'bb': 1, 'ff': 2})
```

Or:

```
>print(pd.DataFrame(ser).reset_index().groupby('foo').count())
     idx
foo     
aa     1
bb     1
ff     2
```

My question is could I / how would I do the same only using `Series.groupby(?????).count()` ?

Edit: Thank you both for answering this, got to learn two new things today :) +1 to both! I am going to accept @jezrael 's answer as it is more exact, plus it allows me to solve my more complex problem I simplified to get to the question (get the list of all instances in addition to counting them):

```
>ser.groupby(ser).apply(lambda df:set(df.index))
foo
aa       {a}
bb       {b}
ff    {c, d}
Name: foo, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Series` has no column, but so you can pass `Series` like:

```
print (ser.groupby(ser).count())
foo
aa    1
bb    1
ff    2
Name: foo, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, there's nothing to apply the `groupby` on when you're dealing with a `series`, so you can just count its values.

Would this do?

```
ser.value_counts()
```

---

```
ser.value_counts()
 
ff    2
aa    1
bb    1
```